# What exactly are REST/Web APIs and how are they meant to be used?

Tags: rest

I've searched for this answer in many places, but I just can't seem to understand the purpose of these services.

What exactly are web APIs meant to do? I've used Spring Boot quite extensively over the past few months, though without touching its REST services portion. I was recommended to check out ASP, and specifically use its web-API items, but I have to say I'm just baffled.

How exactly is the returning of just plain data useful? In Spring, I've used models and views, which are great and useful for directing users around. But that doesn't seem to be the goal of REST APIs. So is the main idea to separate the API from the server? But why do that, when I can just as easily separate the model from the controller anyways, following the MVC pattern? As far as I can tell, there's no real way to return a view with the JSON (or whatever format the data is), so that would necessitate another server, just to deal with providing the views, no?

I'm assuming it's faulty, per-existing information that I have that's getting me stuck up here, but I just don't understand what's the point of a service that only spits out data, yet is far more removed than the model in MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What exactly are web APIs meant to do?

The best summary that I know of comes from Roy Fielding

> REST is intended for long-lived network-based applications that span multiple organizations.

The reference application for the REST architectural style is the World Wide Web.

The point being that, if your API is "of the web", then you get to take full advantage of the work that has already been done for you: browsers, caches, servers, well understood media-types, code-on-demand, and so on.

> is the main idea to separate the API from the server?

Really, the main idea is to separate the implementation from the messaging.  As far as the outside world is concerned, your service is just a web site.

[image: On the Internet, nobody knows you're a dog.]

Comment: So unless you're a company looking to allow other sources to access your data, there's no real need to every make an API, correct? But if you wanted to make a web site, you'd need a separate server just to handle the relatively small amount of code to handle returning the views?

Answer (score 0):

Web Services are used to fetch the data from some other application, only data is fetched and view is prepared by consuming application.

Example if you pass the customer number to web service then only data is received and its your responsibly to display the data in proper asp/jsp or any other view technology

Comment: ...or not display that data at all. Remember, an API is an interface for programs, like a (G)UI is for users. Nothing needs to be displayed, the client is not automatically a webbrowser. It can be another machine running any HTTP client instead for whatever reason.

Comment: Correct. Agree with you Ulrich